# generated jar file does not contain $1 class file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse project that has this class:

```
public class MyClass{
   private static class AnotherClass{
   }
}
```

I tried checking the generated class files and am expecting 3:

> 1. MyClass.class
> 2. MyClass$AnotherClass.class
> 3. MYClass$1.class -> for the inner class

The problem is I'm only getting the first 2. How do I ensure that the 3rd one is generated as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the third one.  It's for *anonymous* inner classes, and your classes aren't.

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html):

> Inner class definitions produce additional class files. These class
>   files have names combining the inner and outer class names, such as
>   MyClass$MyInnerClass.class.

However, `MYClass$1.class` will be generated only if you have an *anonymous inner class*, which you don't have. *anonymous inner classes* appears as numbers.